# Can't rid get rid of keyboard aliases

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

So my keyboard works... but out of nowhere, extra keys will be pressed when I don't want them.

So most letters work... except for z, x, c.

I press z and it brings up the firefox shorcut sidebar (very weird).  x goes to my previous banshee track. c goes to the next track (it should just type that letter).

Here is what I get when I run `sudo showkey`:

z:

```
zkeycode  44 press
keycode 156 press
keycode  44 release
keycode 156 release
```

x:

```
xkeycode  45 press
keycode 184 press
keycode  45 release
keycode 184 release
```

c:

```
ckeycode  46 press
keycode 185 press
keycode  46 release
keycode 185 release
```

A normal letter is just one keycode, eg:

```
akeycode  30 press
keycode  30 release
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't know how to get rid of these parasite keys or reset my keyboard.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2, with Mate 1.12.1.